# Facial features detection using OpenCV Android

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, face-detection

I need to develop a facial features detection application by which I could be able to detect eyes,nose,lips,head along with its face. For this I opted for OpenCV. I had gone through many tutorials and also sample projects. There I could see the usage of haarcascade files through which I could detect the facial features while recording a video. As I know the location of haar cascade file.

But no site could tell me the complete implementation of haarcascade files in OpenCV android project.

Kindly provide me some sites regarding or give me some brief knowledge regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

That is a good approach for detecting faces using openCV. Since you are using android, you will probably not find code written in java but you can always modal it to work on android too. This is what I believe is the best approach. http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html#gsc.tab=0

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html

This is another detailed use of different approaches using OpenCV.
Hope it helps, if you need help in changing the code you have to post what you've done so far and then I would be happy to help! Cheers!